# Compound pointer traits class with method generalizing make_shared and make_unique?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, smart-pointers, unique-ptr, std

For `std::unique_ptr<T>`, we have `std::make_unique<T[]>()`;
For `std::shared_ptr<T>`, there's `std::make_shared<T[]>()`.

A known aphorism in computer science is that we have either none of something, one of something, or arbitrarily many. Well, in this case we're talking about compound pointers, or pointer-like objects. And there are definitely others beyond these two (Example: [smart pointers for CUDA-related memory](https://codedocs.xyz/eyalroz/cuda-api-wrappers/unique__ptr_8hpp.html)).

Well, I would expect to have something like the following function:

```
template <typename Ptr>
inline Ptr make(size_t count);

template <typename T, class Deleter = std::default_delete<T>>
inline std::unique_ptr<T[], Deleter> make<std::unique_ptr<T, Deleter>>(size_t count)
{
    return std::make_unique<T[]>(count);
}

template <typename T>
inline std::shared_ptr<T[]> make<std::shared_ptr<T[]>>(size_t count)
{
    return std::make_shared<T[]>(count);
}
```

but within a traits class, e.g.

```
template <typename Ptr>
struct pointer_traits;
```

as `pointer_traits<std::shared_ptr<T>>::make()`. And this traits class would also have an element type, a raw pointer type (if one exists), etc. - similarly to the iterator traits class template, [std::iterator_traits](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits). It would also exist for the plain pointers, whose maker would be

```
template <typename T>
inline T* make<T*>(size_t count)
{
    return new T[](count);
}
```

Can I find such this kind of traits class, or the equivalent thereof, in the standard library? I tried and failed... If it doesn't exist, has something similar been proposed/discussed by the standard committee?

Comment: It more sounds like you want an allocator, not a trait.  A trait should just supply different types for the traits of a type.

Comment: @NathanOliver: It's not an Standard-library allocator, if that's what you mean...

Comment: No, not a standard allocator but a `maker` function doesn't follow with the traits classes.  For instance [`std::pointer_traits`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/pointer_traits) doesn't provide a way to make a pointer, it just defines things about it.

Comment: @NathanOliver: So that's an answer. Why didn't I think of looking for `std::pointer_traits` myself? ... But still, for pointer classes which have an associated allocation mechanism, like shared and unique - shouldn't pointer_traits have them?

Comment: You know what, it probably should.  I just looked at `allocator_traits` and it has the allocator functions built in.  Looks like you might want to submit a proposal.

Comment: @NathanOliver: I call dibs! I'll try to get to it later this week.

Comment: Cool.  Maybe add an answer with a link to the proposal when you do?

Comment: Sure, you CAN define this sort of thing, but why? That is, do you have a motivating example? In what sort of generalized algorithm might I want to create an object and have a pointer-like thing to the object which [insert semantics here]?

Comment: @aschepler: Basically, the motivating example is that I have some code which I want to have run for both regular unique_ptr's, pinned-memory unique_ptr's, and possibly regular ptr's. And - it does allocation.

Comment: @einpoklum Yes, I understand that this function template can have different specializations. That's a description of the capabilities of `make` (an inside view), but "some code" is not an example of a reason to use it (an outside view).

Comment: @aschepler: Yes, you're right, but it's enough of a motivation for a SO question :-P

Answer (score 0):

Based on @NathanOlliver's insight and suggestion:

The standard library has a [`std::pointer_traits`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/pointer_traits) class, but that one does not have functions which actually perform allocation. It may be useful to propose this to the C++ standards committee, and I'm going to at least try to pursue it soon. Will post an update here if anything comes of it.